# How do I plot a rectangular image of a rotated map in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, projection

I'll preface this by admitting that this is my first post to Stack Overflow, so apologies if I miss some of the finer points.

I am creating a series of maps of the Antarctic Peninsula in ggplot2 using a vector shapefile of the coastline. Creating the basic map works fine:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)

# Import shapefile
peninsula <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/filepath", layer = "filename")
peninsula <- fortify(peninsula)

basic <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = peninsula, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               color = "gray30", size = 0.25, fill = "gray30", alpha = 0.8) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white", linetype = "dotted")) +
  coord_map(project="stereographic", orientation=c(-90,-55,0),
            ylim = c(-68, -60), xlim = c(-70, -42)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "")
basic
```

Which produces the following map:
[image: See here for image]

What I would really like to do, however, is rotate the map counter-clockwise, so that the axis of the Peninsula and island groups to the northeast are vertical (allowing me to put several maps together for publication). I can change the `orientation` argument to `=c(-90,-55,-35)` in order to rotate the map,

[image: link to rotated map]

but I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to reset the x and y limits to "crop" the map extent.

It would seem that a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977511/how-do-you-rotate-the-view-of-a-map-in-ggmap?newreg=66aaa6b142e14910bbf59bdc60a0e086) a while back, but there hasn't been a response yet.

I'm not wedded to the stereographic projection, but I haven't found any other choices that make it easier to both rotate the map and narrow the plotted extent.

Of course, I could simply make the maps like this, and then crop and add new Lat/Lon labels in another program, but it would be better if R could produce the maps directly.